# How rails ajax response should be handle in that case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new with rails , i know well how to do ajax with jquery, but not understand how rails doing that.

Simple example to understand how rails ajax works:

the case - insert ajax response to result div:

view:

```
<div id="result">1result,2result, </div>

<%= form_tag('/mycontroller',{:class =>"myform",:remote => true}) do %>
    <input name="myinput" type="text">
    <button type="submit" class="btn"> add </button>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
      render :json => "3result";
end
```

What should i add to insert the 3result inside div after response success?and which code should i add to treat error case?

Answer (score 1):

you can put this code on your controller

render :update do |page|
      page << "$('#result').append('3result')"
end

and make sure you have 'jquery-rails' gem installed.

you can use that area to to check error and render something different.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify my controller code as such:

```
def create
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    if (success_condition)
      format.js
    else
      format.js { render :js => "alert('Unsuccessful!');" }
    end
  end
end
```

I would create a view called create.js.erb containing:

```js
$("#result").html("3result") // or whatever you want it to do...
```

(Note: that Javascript assumes you have JQuery installed.)

Comment: Of course; you can use erb tags, i.e.) `alert("<%= @variable.name %>");` inside of .js.erb files!